# Phonegap - Error - Keystore alias not recognized

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-2.0.0, code-signing-certificate

I am strugging to sign an Android app using Phonegap Build

I get the following error:

```
Error - Keystore alias not recognized
```

I am using this to create the keystore in my terminal:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore name.keystore
```

-alias alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -storepass password

What should I be using for the 'name' and 'alias', am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 28):

Try this way.
  https://github.com/amirudin/build/wiki/Android-Signing

If the alias is not recognized, the alias field you provided was not found on the keystore file that you uploaded. If the keystore format was invalid, you may not have uploaded the correct files. If the password was incorrect, you may have entered it incorrectly.

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer/documentation!  Was able to get it working right away.

Comment: thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaanks :)