# Error signing android app on phonegap

Tags: android, phonegap-build, android-keystore

I am trying to generate an apk on phonegap

This has worked several times and all that has been altered is some of the source code.

> Error - Keystore uploaded with wrong alias - You can fix this [here][1]

I tried a previously succesful build and that generates teh same error.

The link provides no help.

Any ideas?

Comment: The error message is pretty self explanatory, the alias you are trying to use with your keystore is not correct. This was the first result on Google when I searched "Error - Keystore uploaded with wrong alias": http://stackoverflow.com/a/18691460/2168085

Comment: As I said it has previously worked.  The alias was correct and has not been changed

Comment: The keystore could have also become corrupt, you say that it's not working for any build now so that can be another avenue for you to research.

Answer (score 0):

There was no error with what I was doing.

I waited 5 hours, changed nothing and tried again and it worked.

Missleading error message that I could find little help on.  Something was wrong with phonegap side of things.